# Simple.Data building the Select Statement Dynamically

Tags: simple.data

Is there a way to build the `Select statement` in parts? I am building a dynamic query by working through loops, which works well for the FROM / JOIN aspects, but can't make the Select work...

e.g. rather than this:

```
var results = query.Select(
    u1.FirstName.As("AssistantName"),
    u2.FirstName.As("LeadName")
);
```

something like this:

```
var select = new SelectBuilder();
select.Add(u1.FirstName.As("AssistantName"));
select.Add(u2.FirstName.As("LeadName"));
var results = query.Select(select);
```

Any guidance much appreciated!

Comment: I think you can pass an IEnumerable of columns to the Select method, but I can't remember for sure, which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Columns, as in an IEnumerable<dynamic>, or a specific column type?  IEnumerable<dynamic> didn't seem to work...

Comment: It works.  IEnumerable<SimpleReference> does the trick.  Feel free to change your comment into an answer.

Comment: Done. Thanks for letting me know it worked. I was in Disney World at the time and couldn't check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an IEnumerable<SimpleReference> to the Select method, for example:

```
var columns = new List<SimpleReference>();
columns.Add(u1.FirstName.As("AssistantName"));
columns.Add(u2.FirstName.As("LeadName"));
var results = query.Select(columns).ToList();
```